# Brace expansion in zsh - how to concatenate two lists for file selection?

Tags: concatenation, zsh, braces

In `zsh`, one can create an expression of {nx..ny}, for example to select files x to y inside a folder.

For example, `{1..50}` selects items, files, etc. from 1 to 50.

How can I concatenate two two brace expansions into one?
Example: I would like to select `{1..50}` and `{60..100}` for one and the same output.

Comment: What's wrong with using two brace expansions, as in `echo {1..50} {60..100}`?

Comment: You are correct insofar as ```echo {1..50} {60..100}``` works just fine. However, I had to insert the two brace expansions into another script or code, and then this script failed. The solution that someone provided below, that is, ```{{1..50},{60..100}}``` works just fine in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest brace expansions, so this will work:

```bash
> print {{1..50},{60..100}}
1 2 3 (lots of numbers) 49 50 60 61 (more numbers) 99 100
```

Brace expansions support lists as well as sequences, and can be included in strings:

```bash
> print -l file{A,B,WORD,{R..T}}.txt
fileA.txt
fileB.txt
fileWORD.txt
fileR.txt
fileS.txt
fileT.txt
```

Note that brace expansions are not glob patterns. The `{n..m}` expansion will include every value between the start and end values, regardless of whether a file exists by that name.  For finding files in folders, the `<->` glob expression will usually work better:

```bash
> touch 2 3 55 89
> ls -l <1-50> <60-100>
-rw-r--r--  1 me  grp  0 Feb 18 06:52 2
-rw-r--r--  1 me  grp  0 Feb 18 06:52 3
-rw-r--r--  1 me  grp  0 Feb 18 06:52 89
```

Comment: Thank you. ```{{1..50},{60..100}}``` solved my problem. So what I needed were additional braces around the two expansions including a comma between both.